# Using ObjectFactory in Spring 5 to instantiate a list of prototype objects

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

In Spring 5 I am trying to find a list of classes that implement a particular interface, instantiate them, do some stateful processing, then repeat the process resetting the state.  If didn't have to repeat the process inside a single method call I could just use prototype scoped classes and every time the method was called I would get a new object.  And if it was just one object I could use ObjectFactory to create new instances, but how can I create a list of objects that implement a particular interface using ObjectFactory?

Code would look something like this:

```
  ObjectFactory<WidgetInterface> objectFactory = ...  
  while(hasMoreData()) {
        List<WidgetInterface> newWidgets = objectFactory.instantiateObjects()
        newWidgets.forEach(//do logic)
```

Answer (score 2):

My version is  5.1.6, using `ObjectProvider`, it extends  `ObjectFactory`  and `Iterable`.

Answer (score 0):

I think ObjectFactory gives you a new instance each time if the bean is a prototype.

You can just autowire the ObjectFactory and call getObject().